# How to get only first row grouped by multiple columns?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to select a few columns, but only keep the first row grouped by the columns.

If I use

```
select distinct item_no, item_type, item_name
from `table`
where item_name!='UNKNOWN'
```

It can give me two rows for one item_no, if item_type and item_name don't match in the two rows.

sample output:

```
item_no  item_name  item_type
1        table      A
1        tables     A
2        chair      B
```

How do I make sure I only get the first row grouped by three columns?

Expected output:

```
item_no  item_name  item_type
1        table      A
2        chair      B
```

I'm using BigQuery so standard SQL

Comment: what are the sample rows that you are getting? Please also put it in your post. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a group by item_no then get the mininum value of item_name and item_type.

```
    SELECT 
            item_no,
            MIN(item_name) as item_name,
            MIN(item_type) as item_type
    FROM 
            `table` 
    GROUP BY
            item_no
```

Comment: Thanks. So MIN gets the first row even if it's a text value?

Comment: yes, it will get the first row even if it is a text or int or any data type. pls accept and upvote my answer too. thanks.

Comment: unfortunately this is not correct! `first` and `min` are totally different things!! In order for you to get first row - you need to have something that would define logical order of rows! note: there is no physical order in bq tables, so you cannot expect that row with `table` will be first or with `tables`

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant how can you improve the answer?

Comment: It is not about improving the answer! it is more about setting expectations! The question as it is asked right now - does not have correct answer (read my comments above to see why). in cases like this  - we usually do not answer till OP fix their question

Answer (score 1):

You can use Row_NUMBER() method over item_no and then in outer query you can select only those rows where row_number is 1 (i.e. its first occurrence, ascending ).
e.g.

````
```SELECT item_no, item_name, item_type
   FROM (
       SELECT *
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY item_no ) as row_number
       FROM <table_name>) SOURCE
   WHERE SOURCE.row_number = 1```
````